# How can I automatically escape quotes in content when exporting from MySql to an sql file?

Tags: mysql, database, import, joomla, quotes

We have a Joomla website which we want to copy over to another host website. So far everything has been copied except for the database. The problem we're experiencing is as follows:

After exporting the database information from our old website into an .sql file and trying to import it into an empty database on our new host, it seems text (content) on the website seems to break off at various points. I've found out that it's because of the single quotes `'` in the text, such as `"You're welcome"`. Instead of those two words, it only says `You`. I know that the quotes break up the SQL queries (like in an SQL injection), but how would I go about properly importing the database? Or do I have to change the way I export it first?

We are using phpMyAdmin to export (and import) our information.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. `After exporting the database information from our old website into an .sql file` how are you doing the export?

Comment: We're using phpMyAdmin to export (and import) our information. (added to original post)

Comment: I assume you have no command line access on the remote servers to run a `mysqldump` from?

Comment: Anyway, phpMyAdmin shouldn't be doing this. Are you 100% sure the exported data already has this problem, and it's nothing that happens later? Can you check the dump file to make sure?

Comment: I've checked the .sql file I've exported, here's an example of how it looks (and where I think it fails). I've shortened it a little bit and removed excess HTML and such.

As you can see, at the start of the content (`you're`) there's a single quote, on which it stops. At least, that's what I'm guessing and that's how it looks on our website.

`(17, 'Welcome', 'home', '', 'Dear Visitor, You’re more than welcome on our web site.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced the same thing, I think it's a bug in the phpMyadmin export function. There is no good way that I know of to clean up the dump due to the fact that you can't do a simple search and replace to escape the quotes.

There is a very simple solution however. Use JoomlaPack (now called Akeeba Backup) when you need to move sites. It packs the entire site and DB in to a nice neat ZIP file and it includes a quick installer. Shouldn't take more than a few minutes to move an entire site and be up and running.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606

Comment: Thank you for your response! A brief question, though: will I be able to just export the database? I'm not particularly interested in the files since they've already been transferred.

Comment: You can control what gets backed up if you don't want to get all of the files. I've never done it that way but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Using the Joomla component you recommended me, we've managed to successfully export (and import) the database. Thank you very much for your help. Extremely useful component too.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but it is not joomla database. In this how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post but there is also a fairly simple solution for a find/replace.

If you use a text editor that supports regex find/replaces (I use Sublime Text 2), you can quickly throw something together to match a pattern. This probably won't work for all data, but it has worked for me in instances I have had this issue.

You'll want to search for:

```
(\w)'(\w)
```

and replace with:

```
$1\\'$2
```

This will find any word character with a single quote and another word character next to it and replace with an escaped version. In most cases I deal with the problems are in text with English contractions so this works out for this scenario. It may not work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your old post.  I just encountered this with a phpmyadmin backup.